# $f$ analytic and bounded in $\mathbb C$ \ $\mathbb Z$, what is $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ analytic and bounded in $\mathbb C$ \ $\mathbb Z$, $f(2i)=2i$, what can we say about $f$? $f$ cannot have a pole at any point, this is very clear, if the limit exists at integers, we can say $f$ is constant, what else can we do?,

Now can we say that $f$ has no essential singularity as well, because if there were any Big Picard theorem would contradict the fact that it is bounded. Hence $f$ must have removable singularites?

Comment: See if your book has a result about what you can say when a function is analytic and bounded in a neighborhood of a point, but not defined at the point.

Comment: I think all such points are removable singularites?

Comment: So can you solve it with that information?

Answer (score 1):

As the function is bounded and analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ we know that there is a function $g(z)$ which is entire and $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$. As $f(2i)=g(2i)=2i$ we know that $g=2i$ for all $z$ as $g$ is holomorphic and bounded, and the only bounded holomorphic functions are constant functions.

But we can't conclude something like $f$ to be holomorphic, as we don't know anything about the values it takes in $\mathbb{Z}$, so we can't really say a lot about the function $f$. We don't even know if it is defined in $\mathbb{Z}$ at all.

Comment: You meant "don't know anything about the values it takes in $\mathbb Z$", right?  In fact, we don't even know that it *has* values there.  The question could be understood to say that $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb Z$ is the whole domain of $f$. Let's adopt that understanding; then you've completely answered the question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass oh right sry gonna fix that